# How to increase the size of image using python?

Tags: python, image-resizing, conv-neural-network

I have images of size `48x48`. I want to increase its size to `150x150` for training using transfer learning(CNN). What is the possible way to do this? I want to increase the image size in such a way that the resolution remains same without any loss of data.

Comment: You can either do padding or resize(zooming the image) just the same you do for reducing using PIL or cv2.resize function. Just use the same. but the thing is after increasing the image size(input if they are two small) to 150*150 you might get not so good result but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

you can use without problem the `tensorflow.image.resize` method

```
tf.image.resize(X, [150, 150])
```

if you read the doc of tensorflow, it states that you can do down sampling and up sampling, with different methods

The method argument expects an item from the image.ResizeMethod enum, or the string equivalent. The options are:

- **bilinear:** Bilinear interpolation. If antialias is true, becomes a
  hat/tent filter function with radius 1 when downsampling.
- **lanczos3:** Lanczos kernel with radius 3. High-quality practical filter but may have some ringing, especially on synthetic images
- **lanczos5:** Lanczos kernel with radius 5. Very-high-quality filter but may have stronger ringing.
- **bicubic:** Cubic interpolant of Keys. Equivalent to Catmull-Rom kernel. Reasonably good quality and faster than Lanczos3Kernel,
  particularly when upsampling.
- **gaussian:** Gaussian kernel with radius 3, sigma = 1.5 / 3.0.
- **nearest:** Nearest neighbor interpolation. antialias has no effect when used with nearest neighbor interpolation.
- **area:** Anti-aliased resampling with area interpolation. antialias has no effect when used with area interpolation; it always
  anti-aliases.
- **mitchellcubic:** Mitchell-Netravali Cubic non-interpolating filter. For synthetic images (especially those lacking proper prefiltering),
  less ringing than Keys cubic kernel but less sharp.

[here details](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize)

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# random image data
image_data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(48,48,3)).astype(np.uint8)

image_small = Image.fromarray(image_data)

# there are many settings you can play here, depending on how you want the image resized
image_large = image_small.resize((120,120))

np.array(image_large)
```